# Duplicate lines in a table as times as value has parameter of a column (in R or in Excel)

Tags: r, duplicates, equals

For a stat. analysis in R I need to modify my raw table with a numeric column “SumBirds”  = 4, 7, 12, 20,  etc (table1)  to a new  table2 , where each segment of a column “bird” has  so “1” (one bird) and all others lines of the raw table are duplicated as many times, as value has parameter “SumBird”.

How can I do it in R or in EXCEL (where I prepare my data)?

Examples:
Table1 (raw table)

```
Sumbird     Temp    OutHum
4           28.7    69
6           22.3    58
```

Table 2 (modificated table)

```
bird    Temp    OutHum
1       28.7    69
1       28.7    69
1       28.7    69
1       28.7    69
1       22.3    58
1       22.3    58
1       22.3    58
1       22.3    58
1       22.3    58
1       22.3    58
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use some wrapper in order to make it easier

```
library(splitstackshape)
cbind(bird = 1, expandRows(df, "Sumbird"))
#     bird Temp OutHum
# 1      1 28.7     69
# 1.1    1 28.7     69
# 1.2    1 28.7     69
# 1.3    1 28.7     69
# 2      1 22.3     58
# 2.1    1 22.3     58
# 2.2    1 22.3     58
# 2.3    1 22.3     58
# 2.4    1 22.3     58
# 2.5    1 22.3     58
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `rep`

```
 res <- cbind(bird=1,raw[,-1][rep(1:nrow(raw), raw$Sumbird),])
 row.names(res) <- NULL
 res
 #   bird Temp OutHum
 #1     1 28.7     69
 #2     1 28.7     69
 #3     1 28.7     69
 #4     1 28.7     69
 #5     1 22.3     58
 #6     1 22.3     58
 #7     1 22.3     58
 #8     1 22.3     58
 #9     1 22.3     58
 #10    1 22.3     58
```

#### data

```
 raw<- structure(list(Sumbird = c(4L, 6L), Temp = c(28.7, 22.3),
 OutHum = c(69L, 58L)), .Names = c("Sumbird", "Temp", "OutHum"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Note: The `structure(list(..` output is the one you get by using `dput`.  For your dataset, you read it using `read.csv`. i.e

```
 raw <- read.csv("C:\pathtofile\\rawtable.csv",sep=";")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Please, could you add  in scripts theirs beginnings (I am new in R, and can’t understand  for this short note where I need to  put my raw table).
At first I open it: 
raw<-read.csv("C:\\*** \\rawtable.csv",sep=";")
It has columns like in a table1 : Sumbird, Temp, OutHum.
And then? What shall I do for go to the final scripts that you given?

Comment: Yes, I just found it by myself! Thank you, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

So in short (I used here the first answer, but the second answer also works)

For the raw table (in my example - table1):

```
df<-read.csv("C:\\***\\rawtable.csv",sep=";")
df
library(splitstackshape)
test<-cbind(birds = 1, expandRows(df, "Sumbirds"))
test
```

Then I copied the resulting table (test) in the R-window to a txt file (Notepad) and then open it in EXEL (by "fixed width" format) that open txt file in ordinary xls format. (Don't know other way to move the resulting table from R to EXEL , but maybe they exist).

But if the resulting table (test) is too big I use this:

```
test[c(1:5000),] - represent first 5000 lines of all columns of the "test" table, etc.
```